# Pause Menu Buttons not drawing

Tags: c#, class, xna

currently working on a pause menu for an space invader game, problem I've got however  is that when pressing the enter key the game displays the pause menu but

1. it doesn't display the buttons: btnResume & btnMainMenu within the pause menu

&

1. my sprite in the game can still operate e.g. Rotate either via the left & arrows keys & shoot bullets via the space bar.

Preferably I would like to get the buttons to display but also I would like to see it that my sprite is frozen in place including bullets instead of them flying across the screen when game is paused.

Code is below:

```
namespace Rotationgame
{

/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


    // Different Windows
    enum GameState
    {
        MainMenu,
        Playing,
    }
    GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;

    // Screeb Adjustments
    int screenWidth = 1250, screenHeight = 930;

    // Main Menu Buttons
    button btnPlay;
    button btnQuit;

    // Pause Menu & buttons
    bool paused = false;
    button btnResume;
    button btnMainMenu;




    Vector2 spriteVelocity;
    const float tangentialVelocity = 0f;
    float friction = 1f;

    Texture2D spriteTexture;
    Rectangle spriteRectangle;



    // The centre of the image
    Vector2 spriteOrigin;

    Vector2 spritePosition;
    float rotation;

    // Background
    Texture2D backgroundTexture;
    Rectangle backgroundRectangle;


    // Shield
    Texture2D shieldTexture;
    Rectangle shieldRectangle;

    // Bullets
    List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
    KeyboardState pastKey;



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        shieldTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Shield");
        shieldRectangle = new Rectangle(517, 345, 250, 220);

        spriteTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerShipright");
        spritePosition = new Vector2(640, 450);

        backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
        backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1250, 930);

        // Screen Adjustments
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        IsMouseVisible = true;


        // Main menu Buttons & locations
        btnPlay = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Playbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnPlay.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 310));

        btnQuit = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Quitbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnQuit.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 580));






        // Pause menu buttons & locations


        btnResume = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Playbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnResume.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 310));

        btnMainMenu = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Quitbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnMainMenu.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 580));

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();



        // Allows the game to exit
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                if(btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
                btnPlay.Update(mouse);

                if (btnQuit.isClicked == true)
                    this.Exit();
                    btnQuit.Update(mouse);

                  break;

            case GameState.Playing:

                  if (!paused)
                  {
                      if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                      {
                          paused = true;
                          btnResume.isClicked = false;
                      }
                  }
                  else if (paused)
                  {
                      if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))

                      if (btnResume.isClicked)
                          paused = false;
                      if (btnMainMenu.isClicked) CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
                  }


                break;


        }


        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && pastKey.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
            Shoot();
        pastKey = Keyboard.GetState();

        spritePosition = spriteVelocity + spritePosition;

        spriteRectangle = new Rectangle((int)spritePosition.X, (int)spritePosition.Y,
            spriteTexture.Width, spriteTexture.Height);
        spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteRectangle.Width / 2, spriteRectangle.Height / 2);

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) rotation += 0.025f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) rotation -= 0.025f;

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            spriteVelocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
            spriteVelocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
        }
        else if (Vector2.Zero != spriteVelocity)
        {
            float i = spriteVelocity.X;
            float j = spriteVelocity.Y;

            spriteVelocity.X = i -= friction * i;
            spriteVelocity.Y = j -= friction * j;


            base.Update(gameTime);

        }
        UpdateBullets();
    }

    public void UpdateBullets()
    {
        foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
        {
            bullet.position += bullet.velocity;
            if (Vector2.Distance(bullet.position, spritePosition) > 760)
                bullet.isVisible = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            if(!bullets[i].isVisible)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;


            }


        }
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"));
        newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation),(float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 3f + spriteVelocity;
        newBullet.position = spritePosition + newBullet.velocity * 5;
        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        if(bullets.Count() < 25)
            bullets.Add(newBullet);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
                btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
                btnQuit.Draw(spriteBatch);

                break;

            case GameState.Playing:
                // Drawing Background
                spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle, Color.White);

                // Drawing Shield
                spriteBatch.Draw(shieldTexture, shieldRectangle, Color.White);

                // Drawing Bullets
                foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
                    bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);

                // Drawing Player's Character
                spriteBatch.Draw(spriteTexture, spritePosition, null, Color.White, rotation, spriteOrigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);


                if (paused)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("PauseMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
                    btnResume.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    btnMainMenu.Draw(spriteBatch);
                }

                break;






        }

        spriteBatch.End();
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `Update` method to move your bullet and player movement code into the `Playing` section of your `Update` method.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

    // Allows the game to exit
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        this.Exit();

    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu:
            if(btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
            btnPlay.Update(mouse);

            if (btnQuit.isClicked == true)
                this.Exit();
                btnQuit.Update(mouse);

              break;

        case GameState.Playing:
              if (paused)
              {
                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))

                  if (btnResume.isClicked)
                      paused = false;
                  if (btnMainMenu.isClicked) CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
              }
              else if (!paused)
              {
                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                  {
                      paused = true;
                      btnResume.isClicked = false;
                  }


                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && pastKey.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
                      Shoot();

                  pastKey = Keyboard.GetState();
                  spritePosition = spriteVelocity + spritePosition;

                  spriteRectangle = new Rectangle((int)spritePosition.X, (int)spritePosition.Y, spriteTexture.Width, spriteTexture.Height);
                  spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteRectangle.Width / 2, spriteRectangle.Height / 2);

                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) rotation += 0.025f;
                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) rotation -= 0.025f;

                  if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                  {
                      spriteVelocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
                      spriteVelocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
                  }
                  else if (Vector2.Zero != spriteVelocity)
                  {
                      float i = spriteVelocity.X;
                      float j = spriteVelocity.Y;

                      spriteVelocity.X = i -= friction * i;
                      spriteVelocity.Y = j -= friction * j;


                      base.Update(gameTime);

                  }
                  UpdateBullets();
                  break;
              }
          }
    }
```

I think you should have `Paused` as an additional GameState, instead of checking for its paused value in the GameState.Playing scenario.

Comment: I've tried something similar to this before and got a separate screen for the Paused menu, however what what I'm trying to achieve is a pause screen within the game in which the pause menu itself has a lowered opacity so users can still see the game instead of getting a completely new GameState screen

Comment: Did you try specifying a location for your buttons to be drawn in your draw method? Also, don't reload your PauseMenu `Texture2D` in your Draw method, do it in `LoadContent` and store it locally. It will be faster.

Comment: Yes i did  specify a location for them, here:// Pause menu buttons & locations


        `btnResume = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>        ("Playbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnResume.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 310));`

        `btnMainMenu = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>   "Quitbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnMainMenu.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 580));`

Comment: Can you try adding those locations to your `spriteBatch.Draw` call? I dont know if it will make a difference or not, but thats the way I have always done it.

Comment: Right if try copying them from loadcontent & adding to the Draw spriteBatch & it would load up the pause menu but had still no buttons, I also tried removing from loadcontent  and just have them in draw content & pause menu wouldn't open.